# Spring - store object in session without MVC

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a clean javascript + html + css frontend project, which sends a POST request to a backend endpoint.

Backend is a SpringBoot application.

I need to store a shopping cart into server's session and not into browser's session. Previously the project was a Spring MVC + Thymeleaf app, but I am rewriting it to JS + Spring.

In previous app version is was handled by @ModelAttribute and @SessionAttribute annotations, but simple "copy-paste" of all classes and configs does not solve the issue.

Example Controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("basket")
public class LabelDesignController implements IPageModel {

    @ModelAttribute("basket")
    public Basket populateBasketForm() {
        logger.info("[Model Attribute] populating [Basket] form.");
        return new Basket();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/myEndPoint", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object myEndPoint(@ModelAttribute("basket") Basket b, Item newItem) {
        // some logic here
    }
}
```

Item is a POJO class.

EDIT:
forgot to mention, the frontend are static HTML pages with vanilla JavaScript (even no jQuery). they are running on Nginx server. The backend is running on mvn spring-boot:run command.

Comment: Can you please post the stack Trace? (I am assuming there is one..)

Comment: No errors taking place. It seems that with every POST made by front end a new instnace of controller class is being made and new Basket obj created.

Comment: This is really strange..
However I have noticed that you miss the @RequestMapping annotation. Try to put it under  Controller annotation. Something like : @RequestMapping("/myEndPoint")

Comment: Is there any sort of way to setup Spring boot to listen for incomming sessions or so?

Comment: Yes , you can take a look here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-session-attributes